# Merge value of two colums and insert in to another table in ms sql

Tags: mysql, database, join, concatenation

I want to get values from two columns (c1,c2) of a table T1 and then merge them as (c3) and then insert merged value (c3) in a new table T2.  Also it check length of second column (c2), if it is less then 4 characters, insert zeros before vlaue of (C2).

Source Table :   **Table -  T1**

---

```
  C1      |    C2
```

---

```
  101     |   201
  101     |   202
  101     |   203
  101     |   1101
  101     |   1102
  101     |   1103
  102     |   221
  102     |   222
  103     |   2025
```

---

Needed Table  **Table - T2**

---

```
  C3
```

---

```
  1010201
  1010202
  1010203
  1011101
  1011102
  1011103
  1020221
  1020222
  1032025
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO T2 ([C1] ,[C2] ,[C3]) 
SELECT [C1] ,[C2] ,
    CONCAT([C1],'1400', 
        replicate('0', 4 - len(C2)) + cast (C2 as varchar)) as C3
FROM T1 
WHERE [Eligible]='Yes' ORDER  BY C1 ASC, C2 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with chars, then try this:

```
insert into t2 (c3) (select if(char_length(c2)=4,concat(c1,c2),concat(c1,'0',c2)) from t1)
```